# Transaction UnderPriced error ethers.js

Tags: blockchain

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ&t=9348s
I was following this course (I was about 7:15 ~ 7:20 in)
I tried to deploy the contract my manually sending a transaction as below:
[image]

and I got an error with the message "transaction underpriced"
I tried increasing the number for gasPrice and gasLimit but it changing anything on gasPrice didn't work. with gasLimit, once it hits 6721975, which is what my ganache GUI shows, it still returns error but with "gas limit exceeded" message. How can I fix this?